# How can I combine the advantages of pen and laptop?

Tags: tools

I like writing on my laptop because I can type quickly. I like writing with a pencil because it is more relaxing and pleasant to edit: The words just flow and there is no bright light.

Are there options that combine the advantages of both?

Comment: There's always coal on the back of a shovel...

Comment: Dictate it into voice recognition software.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Was some famous piece of literature produced that way?

Comment: Abraham Lincoln famously did his schoolwork that way as a child.

Comment: I've put this on hold because questions that solicit list-style answers (as we're seeing here already) aren't a good fit for SE.  Please [edit] to describe what features are important to you and then we can reopen -- describe the *problem you're trying to solve* rather than just taking a survey, and I'm confident the folks here can help you.  Thanks!

Comment: Spraypaint on the side of a building

Answer (score 1):

While die-hard wordsmiths might cringe, dictation is a great way to get your words on paper!

Comment: There's probably a market for a DYAC story, but I don't think you could do a novel that way. Kind of Pynchon meets Dali by way of HAL.

Answer (score 1):

You could always also use a typewriter if you find one somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I like writing with a really great pen. If the instrument feels good in my fingers and makes nice marks on the paper, then I'll enjoy the whole process more.